# backup a file but leave a 0-sized file back with same name?

Tags: windows

Instead of entirely deleting the original file (winrar/totalcopy) is there any method that leaves a 0-sized file in place of the backed-up copy? so that I always know what I already have in my backup before copying new data (sometimes huge) and also without taking up any space.

Comment: Have you considered a real backup system that does incremental or differential backups?

Comment: I don't wanna have to specify locations to backup. "Just drag-and-drop whatever you want backed-up to external drive" works best for me. But that's not the way most backup systems work... would you suggest any to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an empty file on the command line via a few ways:

```
copy nul newfile
type nul > newfile
echo. >nul 2>newfile
...
```

Comment: hmm thanks! but thats a lotta work for me (to do that for every other file copied).

Comment: Well, I was assuming some kind of automation.